# How do I make form input field and button horizontally align?

Tags: python, css, django

I recently added django forms to my html file and it stuffed my css around. I can't seem to line up my input field and button horizontally.

Here is my form code:

```
<form action = "/" method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class = "col-md-6 text-box">
        <div class="input-group" id = "buttonSlider" >
            {% render_field form.email placeholder="email loser, were going shopping" class+="form-control input-hg btn-color flat" %}

            <button class="input-group-addon input-hg btn-color flat" type = "submit">Request Invite</button>

        </div>

    </div>

 </form>
```

The result is this:

[image]

note: I just turned on a dashed border so i could see the outline of the div.

This is the desired result is to have the "Request an Invite" inline with the input field, AND to be all in that darker pink. For some reason it has cut 4/5ths of it out.

If you need anymore html let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing by the css classes you're using bootstrap, if your not or if you're using some other third party utility you should add that detail to your question

Comment: Try to place your `button` outside `div.input-group`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
float: right;
```

for the button.

Comment: Thx @Drenmi .I'm the first time to answer question.